# Animate an element that had display: none?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

**How can I make a hidden element unhidden and transition?**

**Example:**

I want to animate a `<div>` that has `display: none; height: 0px; transition: height 600ms;`.

So on click I add a class with `display: block; height: 100px;`.

The height does not animate.

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/donpinkus/pen/qaoZoG)**

I would prefer a solution that uses `transition`, but if none is available I can use `animation`. I am not looking for any answers that use javascript.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property

You can't animate with display. Use visibility and/or opacity.

Comment: Isn't this a drawback in CSS? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property

Comment: @Jabaluza - yes I know display isn't animatable, but the other properties are. So is the answer that you can't transition ANY property if a singly changed one isn't supported?

Comment: @DonnyP yeah, you can't animate every property.

Answer (score 7):

You're not going to be able to animate it with `display`. If you give your `.submenu` class an `overflow: hidden;` and remove the `display: none;`, it will animate as desired since you're already animating the height from 0.

**CSS**

```
.submenu {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;  /* <-- Add This */
  background: blue;
  transition: height 600ms ease 0ms;
}
```

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/Hunter377/pen/vXjBod)**

```js
$('.menu').click(function(){
  $('.submenu').toggleClass('open');        
});
```

```css
.menu {
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.submenu {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: blue;
  transition: height 600ms ease 0ms;
}
.submenu.open {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <h1>Click me to expand a submenu</h1>
  <div class="submenu">  
    <p>test 1</p>
    <p>test 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful solution! Is there a way to dynamically set the height?
When I put height: auto(or inherit, fit-content, initial, parent, etc), it breaks the animation. Is there a way to set it to fit-content and still get the animation?

Comment: @KrisBonev in order for it to animate properly, there needs to be a defined height (or even width). Let's say you have a div that has a dynamic height (set to auto), and you want to animate it to a height of 300px. All the browser will see is that you want to go to 300px, but it won't know where to animate it **from**. That's why when you animate with CSS, you have to specify a starting point for the animation.